# GET and POST Methods

Tags: html, post, methods, get

I have one application (checkpoint firewall)

That sends formats a URL from variables to form a request using the GET method

```
https://api.example.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=$APIID&user=
$USERNAME&password=$PASSWORD&to=$PHONE&text=$MESSAGE
```

how ever the website I want to use is a basic form using the POST method with the following source.

```
<html>
    <form method="post">
        Number:<input type="text" name="number"/><br/>
        Message:<textarea cols="40" rows="4" name="message"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

I can change the format of the URL as much as I like with in reason, as you can possible guess this is sending SMS text messages.

is there any way to format a URL with the POST method, or create an intermediate webpage that can translate the request?

thank you

EDIT

So this was the kind of thing I had in mind

```
$number = ($_GET["number"]);
$message = ($_GET["message"]);

//for testing the get method echo variables on screen
echo("Number: " . $number . "<br />");
echo("Message: " . $message . "<br />");

//use curl to post variables to second website
$vars = "number-" . $number . "&message=2 . message;
$ch = curl_init( '10.43.23.53' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

this script is hosted by a web site so application A can use its GET method to supply the variables, and the script will re-post them to application B via post. However it does not work and I don't get any result from the response ?

Comment: Curl needed the follow redirect statement. After that it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$apiKey = 'your-api-key-here';
$user = 'your-username-here';
$password = 'your-password-here';
$number = isset($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : null;
$message = isset($_GPOST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;

$url = sprintf('https://api.example.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=%s&user= %s&password=%s&to=%s&text=%s',
    $apiKey, $user, $password, urlencodee($message)
);

// validating message etc. left to OP

$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 8 when I try to run this ?

Comment: i wrote it in the stack overflow text box, seems there was a missing comma

Comment: Also I am not sure what this code achives? I am sure it is me not being that clued up on HTTP methods, but i think this seems to be going from POST to GET? while I need to take a GET string and change it to a POST method.

Comment: right, I think I read your question backwards then! No time to amend now, will see later today. You may want to look into CURL in the mean time.

Comment: Hi cheer I got curl working. :) need to tidy code but does just what I need.:)

Comment: @DevilWAH You should post your own answer then, and accept that instead.

Comment: No sir, you suggested to look at curl and that was what got it to fall in to place.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to send a POST as a GET, they are different methods and a POST requires variables to be sent with the request that are not available in a GET request.

You could in theory create an intermediary which takes the initial GET request and forms a suitable POST requests and send it on to the target server. The actual implementation of this is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: what I was asking is if you can send a POST request like a GET request, ie via a formatted URL, or does it require code to achieve it. So does an intermediary simple reformat the URL and send it on or  is there more to i?